# Object still moving with parent after clearing

Tags: transforms, parent

I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selected clear parent then checked the relation status under the object property pannel. The parent is cleared, but the object is still moving with the rig.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot or post the blend file? It would go a long way to helping us see your situation.

Comment: What's your question? This is a **Question** and **Answer** site: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you checked the constraints menu?